# Automatically install apt packages

Tags: apt

This might be a terrible idea, but is it possible to have non-installed packages automatically installed? That is, instead of seeing this:

```
$ git clone ...
The program 'git' is currently not installed. To run 'git' please ask your administrator to install the package 'git'
```

Seeing this instead:

```
$ git clone ...
Installing package 'git'
...
```

Comment: There was once a proposal to sort of do this in c-n-f (command-not-found). I believe it was never implemented or was reverted though I did use the code in c-n-f for a while. (I think there may have been some obscure issues.)  This was the report, noting that links to the commit are wrong. - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/command-not-found/+bug/224776